# Slider transition after Complete Image

Tags: jquery, slider, supersized

I am using Supersize slider..

I am facing a problem...

if an image is big in size and its takes time to load, then before being fully loaded, the slider gets chaged to new image..

i want to add a feature like when one image is totally downloaded then after that time the slider will transit..

can anybody help me with this sort of problem??

```
EDIT
```

i want to have the slide transit, when the previous image is totally downloaded..

say i have 3 images a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg

a.jpg got transitioned to b.jpg,

b.jpg is a very big file.. untill and unless b.jpg is totally downloaded, it wont get transitioned to give way to c.jpg ......

so the transition may get stopped as per each image untill the image gets totally downloaded......

Comment: Create an image preloader?

Comment: what do u mena by create an image preloader??

Answer (score 0):

Initialize slider after `document` is fully loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //slider initialization.
});
```

Now in html just do it as below.

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="loading.jpg" alt="" id="slider_loading"/></li>
        <li><img src="1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now make css for `slider div` inside witch add `dislpay:none;` rule for all image.

**CSS**

```
#slider ul li img
{
    display:none;
}

#slider_loading
{
    display:block !important;
}
```

now before `slider initialization` code **remove that loading image** as below.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $("#slider_loading").remove();
   //slider initialization.
});
```

and you are done.

Comment: @sazet_rey i just gave you way to archive what you want...it can be apply to whatever slider you are using...

Comment: ok buddy, but supersized slider has some specific features, thats why i wondered, moreover it has an auto transition duration.   will also that be taken on account???

Comment: @sazet_rey when you use window.load it means page is fully loaded including all the images so you don't need to worry about transition duration...because once image are loaded then slider will be activated or created...also you can make use of Stuart answer function...

Comment: ok, i am a bit weak in jquery.. but can u tell me one thing?? is window.load and $(document).ready() different???

Comment: @sazet_rey yes they are as i have told you document.ready fire when document is prepared means html is loaded but window.load fire when content of page is fully loaded...

Comment: i want to have the slide transit, when the previous image is totally downloaded..

say i have 3 images a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg

a.jpg got transitioned to b.jpg,

b.jpg is a very big file.. untill and unless b.jpg is totally downloaded, it wont get transitioned to give way to c.jpg ......

so the transition may get stopped as per each image untill the image gets totally downloaded......

Comment: $(window).load(function() is causing all the images to get downloaded first and then the slider runs....so image which got downlaoded waits for images that didnt get downlaod......... i want images will transit if they get fully downloaded, and when the slider gets encountered with an mage not fully downloaded, it will wait for that image there, and when the image will download completely, it will then transit to next slide

Answer (score 0):

You want to preload your images.

This function will load the images and append them to a container:

```
function preloadImages() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        $('<img />').attr('src', arguments[i]).appendTo('#myImages');
    }
}
```

Call that function on document ready:

```
$(function() {
    preloadImages('a.jpg', 'b.jpg');
    $('#myImages').show();
});
```

In your HTML have:

```
<div id="myImages" style="display:none"></div>
```